# Create the mentioned CSS class not work in HTML web page without having access to HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website from e-commerce platform (Zid)

and I want to edit the mpbile view for Categories section from CSS

howverer, the view I want to make is just to remove the slider and make column photos

so I want to make the mentiond class of CSS in the HTML not working

but I don't have the accesablity to the HTML Structure

so how I can my mentiond CSS class not work?

you can see the capture here:

[image]

as shown it is a slider under the name (الأقســـام)

I want each photo on that slider to be in different row
so it makes a vertical column like that

```
( Photo 1 in line 1
  Photo 2 in line 2
  Photo 3 in line 3 
  .. etc )
```

and all of that must be from the CSS as I don't have the accessibility to HTML file for the website.

Comment: Can you please show us how it looks like by going to inspect of your website?

Comment: sure it is done